# vb creating properties using arrays

Tags: vb.net

I can create a field that is an array for my class just fine.  I am having trouble creating my property as an array.  Do i really need to define each individual property one by one? Or is there a better way to do it.  Everything I try gives me an error.  _Pencil(5) gives me an error.

Public Class Pens

```
Private pens(5) As Integer

ReadOnly Property _Pencil(5) As Integer
    Get
        Return pens(0)
        Return pens(1)
        Return pens(2)
        Return pens(3)
        Return pens(4)
        Return pens(5)
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

I really appreciate all the help.

Update Edwin code works great but I am unable to retrieve the information

Class Markers

```
  Private _pens(5) As Integer

   Public ReadOnly Property Pencil As Integer()
      Get
          Return _pens
      End Get
   End Property

   Sub New()
      _pens(0) = 1
      _pens(1) = 2
      _pens(2) = 3
      _pens(3) = 4
      _pens(4) = 5
      _pens(5) = 6
    End Sub


 End Class
```

This seems to work but when I am unable to see the values of _pens(0) , _pens(1) and so on when i create my object

dim test as New Marker()

test.Pencils <---- i cant see the elements of the array

Thanks

Comment: the explicit 5 param is wrong.  it should probably be a variable (such as `nPen as Integer`) and the return, probably be `pens(nPen)`.  If you are indeed trying to return an array, then `Property Pencil as Integer()` and you still dont need the param

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Sorry anyway you can write the code out so I can see.  If not no worries

Comment: It looks like you're using a different class.  You should do "Dim test as New Pencil"

Comment: Thank you I changed the class to Marker so it would stand out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is its own thing.  You only have to return it without specifying each item.The underscore usually indicates the private field.

Try this:

```
Private _pens(5) as Integer

Public ReadOnly Property Pencil As Integer()
    Get
       Return _pens

    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: ahhh thats what the underscore is for.  Thanks

Comment: That still gives me an error. There is an blue squig under _pens that says Value of type "1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot convert to integer

Comment: Sorry, the parenthesis go after the type with properties. Just updated.

Comment: Now I am having trouble accessing the value when I create an object.  I created a constructor that has and initialize all my _pens(0) =1 _pens(1) = 2 .... and so on.  Now when I create an object says MyPen  MyPen.Pencil<--- doesnt have the _pens(1) value to look at.

Comment: Edwin, I added in your code to my initial question.  Any ideas on why I cant see the elements when create a new object?

Answer (score -2):

try

```
ReadOnly Property Pencil() As Integer
    Get
 Return pens(0)
        Return pens(1)
        Return pens(2)
        Return pens(3)
        Return pens(4)
        Return pens(5)
    End Get
End Property
```

just use pencil() instead of _pencil(5)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that.  When I create a new object of type pencil I am unable to read each value,  u Dim myPen As Pencil myPen.pens() <-- only returns pens(0).

Comment: The execution stops at the first return. The other returns will **Never** run